# Spam check before sending using Zend_Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, spam, zend-mail

I'm using `Zend_Mail` and the following code to send my email messages.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail ->setBodyText($plainBody)
   ->setBodyHtml($htmlBody)
   ->setSubject($subject)
   ->setFrom(FROM_ADDR, FROM_NAME)
   ->addTo($email, $name )
   ->addHeader(MY_HEADER, serialize( array( 'foo' => 'bar' ) ) )
;
```

I need to check the **spam rating** for the prepared message and I'd like to do it using SpamAssassin.

I thought to create a file with the contents and running something such as `exec('spamc $filename')`, but how to get the file content with the full MIME body?
I noticed that there's a `_buildBody()` function in Zend_Mail_Abstract class (`library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php`) that's return that, but that's a `protected` function.

Thanks

Comment: Don't send emails where you have to assume spamassassin might not like them...

Comment: You right, but I'dont know the content. That's a newsletter wysiwyg app, and the user should be able to check if his message could be treated as spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SpamAssasin, then run your email message through `spamc`:

http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/spamc.html

> Spamc is the client half of the spamc/spamd pair. It should be used in
>   place of spamassassin in scripts to process mail. It will read the
>   mail from STDIN, and spool it to its connection to spamd, then read
>   the result back and print it to STDOUT. Spamc has extremely low
>   overhead in loading, so it should be much faster to load than the
>   whole spamassassin program.

You can do use in PHP by:

1. Writing the message into a temporary file and running `shell_exec('spamc < message.tmp')`, or
2. Running the command with [proc_open()](http://id2.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) then send message via `STDIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to simulate a spam check on the recipient's end. That's an interesting idea, but note that the results it will give you will be far from 100% realistic. After all, it's the sending process that adds much of the vital information that helps determine whether an E-Mail is spam (e.g. the sender IP and routes.)

Anyway, to do this, you will probably have to implement a custom `Zend_Mail_Transport` class, based on the example of `Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp`. Any data that transport class sends to the SMTP server, you would have to re-route to a text file. As far as I can see at a cursory glance, it's going to be a  bit of work but not impossible.

Comment: Yes, I want to simulate it. In a nutshell I need to **real** send my message, right? Might be an idea to send it local address `www-data` (php running user) and store it in a Maildir?

Comment: @Fabio sending it to a local address might be the easiest way to go. Alternatively, as said, Zend's encapsulation does make it possible  to write a custom `Zend_Mail_Transport`